# Case when else statement in update set function

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a little bit of code to update the prices in my database which I have set before in an Excel sheet.

For this I need to update 1 of two columns. In case the column "override" is 1 I need to update the column product_override_price otherwise I need to update product_price.

For doing this I wrote the following test code however it tells me I have an error which I can't find.

```
UPDATE `product_prices` 

case when `override` ='1' then SET `product_override_price`= '100' else SET `product_price`= '100' end where `product_id`='6'
```

I would appreciate any help in this. Please note the code needs to be reproduced for 50 other product_id's.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE `product_prices` 
SET `product_override_price` = case when `override` ='1' 
                                    then '100'  
                                    else product_override_price
                               end,
    `product_price`= case when `override` <> '1' 
                          then '100'  
                          else product_price
                     end
where `product_id`='6'
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution juergen. Works like a dream to me!